# Text rendering in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to set grayscale text renderer anti aliasing in WPF, I can do it in XAML by using this attribute:

```
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale"
```

But I need it for painting text on screen, using **FormattedText**, but FormattedText has no option for text rendering and anti aliasing.

I found font sizes under 21 change render mode to cleartype, but I need grayscale always.

Sample code:

```
FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(
    "small text",
    cult_info,
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    rw.font,
    18,
    Brushes.DarkGreen);
Point o2 = new Point(dock_w - 5, origin.Y+ft.Height/8);
Point o3 = new Point(dock_w-5, origin.Y+ft.Height);
Point o4 = new Point(dock_w-5-ft.Width, origin.Y+ft.Height);
ft.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
dc.DrawText(ft, o2);
dc.DrawLine(pen,o3,o4);
```

Comment: And where is the `DrawingContext dc` initialized or assigned?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit in my OnRender method of custom control.

Comment: Why not pass the reference to your custom control instead of `visual` as in my answer? Like `TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(this, TextRenderingMode.Grayscale);`

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I tried it, but not working!

Comment: Weird. I'm afraid I can't help you on this issue then. It has been too long since I've used WPF.

Comment: Can you stay somehow in XAML world? Why do you have to use DC and FormattedText?

Comment: @CsabaToth I need complex custom rendering, not possible in XAML

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(visual, TextRenderingMode.Grayscale);
```

before drawing the text on the context (and I think even before calling `RenderOpen`)?

Comment: I don't use Visual and RenderOpen, I need to change rendering option for a specific DrawingContext or while UserControl.

Comment: Please improve your question by adding more sample code of your specific problem